# Can a website subdirectory be served by a different web server AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns

I came across this link:
[Can a website subdirectory be served by a different web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848605/can-a-website-subdirectory-be-served-by-a-different-web-server)

My question is a more specific. Can a sub subdirectory be served on AWS if the domain is served elsewhere?

I was looking at using Amazon Lightsail to spin up a Wordpress blog.

Has anyone managed it and is it possible? ie. mydomain.com/blog to go on AWS. mydomain.com served elsewhere.

What configuration would I have to do on the AWS side if possible? Would I be looking at going down a different route instead of Amazon Lightsail?

Comment: An easier alternative is to host your blog on a subdomain, `blog.mydomain.com` then it's just normal DNS rules and no proxy.

Comment: I agree @BuhBuh . This is very unlikely in this circumstance though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still a reverse proxy on your `mydomain.com` server,

If you are using NGINX on your domain side of things for example, you would do something like:

```
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://url-to-aws/blog/ ;
}
```

You can refer to the NGINX docs here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Or if you are using Apache on your domain server, you can find their docs here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

The AWS side of things would just be a normal setup with no additional configurations.

Comment: Just to be clear, the guys hosting the domain would have to do 'reverse proxy' on their side.

for the Amazon Lightsail side of things I would also need to configue Apache. Would virtual hosts need to be created?

Comment: The Amazon Lightsail side of things would be a normal webserver, however you decide to set that up. The hosting domain side of things would set up a reverse proxy that forwards to the AWS lightsail site.